# Pirkei Avot cycle in Israel when Pesach starts on Shabbat

Tags: minhag, passover, eretz-yisrael, shavuos, pirke-avot-ethicsof

In 5775, Pesach begins on Shabbat. While those outside Israel observe the 8th day of Pesach on Shabbat, in Israel, because there is no 8th day of Pesach, it will be a "regular" Shabbat. This means that they begin Pirkei Avot a week before those outside Israel. Does this mean that Israel will always be a week ahead of those outside Israel for the entire Pirkei Avot season? Would this same scenario occur when the 2nd day of Shavuot is on Shabbat?